# how to balance position of UIBarButtonItem in toolbar

Tags: iphone, uitoolbar

is it possible to balance the position of button(example toolbar in Safari)?

```
    UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                       initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCompose 
                                       target:self action:@selector(support:)];

        UIBarButtonItem *next = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                       initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay 
                                       target:self action:@selector(support:)];
        [self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:infoButton, next,nil] animated:YES];
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add a flexible space item between the two button items.

More detail is available in Apple's [UICatalog sample code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/UICatalog/). e.g.:

```
// flex item used to separate the left groups items and right grouped items
UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                          target:nil
                                                                          action:nil];
```

Comment: can i ask more question?
is it possible to disable item of self.navigationController.toolbar


thanks

Comment: You should ask a separate question, and try to make the question as complete as possible.